# I cannot scroll down on any page of my website using Android devices

Tags: android, html, css, prestashop, responsive

I've been looking for a way to solve this issue for the past 5 days but none of the solution i found online has worked for me.

I've got a prestashop with a custom theme installed and it's working perfectly on most devices : iPhone, iPad, Computers (mac & pc)

But when using any android devices i cannot scroll down. (Tested every page of the website same issue)

I even connected my phone with adb-server and chrome to try and debug the issue but without luck !

URL is : https://www.lamaisondugadget.fr

Any help would he appreciated.

Comment: Everytime it loads there's an error with "Cleave" at custom.js:782, have you checked on that? iOS does not throw that error...

Comment: I tried to remove the cleave.min.js but the issue remain the same.

Comment: Have you removed also the following code inside /themes/claue/assets/js/custom.js ? var cleave = new Cleave('.input-date', {
    date: true,
    delimiter: '/',
    datePattern: ['d', 'm', 'Y']
});

Comment: Just removed both reference to cleave, but the problem persist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you used `main {overflow: hidden;}`. This not only hides the scrollbar, but also removes the scroll ability.
If you want to hide the scrollbar on mobile devices while keepign scrollability, you have to style the scrollbar with a `width: none;`.

```css
main {   
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer ! Sadly i tried your suggestion and added this to my css : @media (max-width: 492px){ 

main {
    overflow: scroll !important;
}} but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think I find what's the problem. There's a suspicious script in your head:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
  }, { passive: false });
</script>
```

As far as I understand this script is generally used to disable zooming on a webpage (which I think it's not a good behavior anymore).

So my suggestion is to try to remove that script from your project.

Reference: [link](https://qastack.it/programming/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

Comment: Damn.. i saw this code earlier this week but didn't tried to remove it -_- Thanks you so much problem is now solved after removing this part in head! You just made my day sir :)

Comment: Glad I have helped you! :) don’t forget to accept the answer, it could help others